# Mongo database cannot start

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello everyone all help is much appreciated.  Using MongoDB for the first time, I usually use postgresql.  Cannot get any database action, including generating models.  Continually get this error:

Mongo::ConnectionFailure: Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017

The internet says to try these, none of which work:

1-

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo -u mongodb mongod -f /etc/mongodb.conf --repair
sudo start mongodb
sudo status mongodb
```

This returns the error that

rm: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock: No such file or directory

2- This is in a file I put in the initialize folder

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("mydb")
db = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost").db("mydb")
db = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost", 27017).db("mydb")
```

The problem seems to stem from a path, which I have no idea how it works or how to alter it, so if the advice is to alter paths and folders etc. please be very specific.  Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Your layout looks like ubuntu or similar. Run `cat /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` or possibly "mongod.log" depending on version, then look for lines just before shutdown. It should tell you the reason why this has not started. Post the lines around there with your question if you still are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The mongo daemon has not successfully started.

Usually you do 
`sudo mongod`

Make sure you can connect to the database by typing `mongo` on the command line which should connect you to the daemon running on 27017.

Then try running your ruby code again.

Comment: Hey Jeff and Neil, neither of those work.

sudo mongod prompts me for a password then says that mongod is not a valid command, neither is mongo.  I definately have these gems installed so I find that strange.

And when I run     cat /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

it says no such file or directory exists

Comment: Just to confirm: have you installed mongodb on your system? the gem is only the ruby interface to mongodb and does not include mongo itself. The installers are found here: https://www.mongodb.org/downloads